# Error references objectHydrator in xamarin forms

Tags: xamarin.forms

i´m working with xamarin forms and have a error with ObjectHydrator , please helpme

```
> Gravedad  Código  Descripción Proyecto    Archivo Línea   Estado suprimido
Error       Can not resolve reference: `Foundation.ObjectHydrator`, referenced by `XamarinListasDemo`. Please add a NuGet package or assembly reference for `Foundation.ObjectHydrator`, or remove the reference to `XamarinListasDemo`.    XamarinListasDemo.Android
```

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/zNc9z.png)

in the image are all the erros

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Have a try with follow steps :

1. Right click your solution
2. Select **Manage Nuget Packages for Soltions...**

[image]

3. In **Browser** view serch **ObjectHydrator**

[image]

4. Install above selected Nuget Package to check whether it works .

[image]

Official document about installing Nuget package : https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/nuget/quickstart/install-and-use-a-package-in-visual-studio